# How to make javascript card overflow with wrap and inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a bunch of `div`s line up inline and scroll as they go out of screen.

This is what I have. Sorry for no formatting for the `card` div.

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.card {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
</div>
```

It works fine when the contents fit within the `card` div. But things overflow outside the card when they don't fit because of `white-space: nowrap`. However, if I change the white-space attribute to `white-space: initial/normal` or anything, the overflow problem is solved, but then the cards don't scroll anymore and wrap around to the next row:

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: initial;
}
.card {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card"><h2>Card content content content content Card content content content content Card content content content content Card content content content content Card content content content content </h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
  <div class="card"><h2>Card</h2></div>
</div>
```

I am thinking maybe `display: inline-block` and the `white-space:nowrap` are conflicting but I don't know enough to know if that's true. Thanks for any help!

[Code credits](https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6)

Comment: You have formatting error in your css-code in second example.

Comment: that was leftover code from scss that I forgot to change to css. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below snippet, and confirm if this is what you want.

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card content content content content Card content content content content Card content content content content Card content content content content Card content content content content</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>Card</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I knew it was going to be something like this I was overlooking. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can have `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block`

```
.card {
  float: left;
}
```